# Выставление прав на папки FTP через скрипт

Tags: права, скрипт, php, html

Здравствуйте, товарищи программисты.

Есть сайт, где недавно появилась потребность иметь в админке "волшебную кнопочку", при нажатии на которую менялись бы права доступа сразу на несколько папок.

Названия папок:

- /cache/
- /tmp/
- /media/
- /images/

В папке `/images/` желательно иметь возможность менять права сразу и на все вложенные файлы и папки.

При этом, касательно папки `/media/` нужно разрешить доступ только к этой папке, но ни в коем случае не на вложенные в нее файлы и папки.

Как такое сделать? Я так представляю, что это должен быть вызов .php-файла.
Например, ссылка типа:

```
<a href="prava.php" target="_blank">Изменить права доступа на 777</a>
```

А в файле prava.php будет описана функция изменения прав доступа.
Вот только я очень слабо разбираюсь в PHP. Пожалуйста, подскажите что и как.

А вообще шикарно было бы, если бы вместо открытия нового окна "prava.php" просто рядом с кнопкой выводилась надпись "Выполнено!".

Я буду вам *ОЧЕНЬ* благодарен за помощь, а то вручную туда-сюда менять уже сильно надоело.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

сменить права на папку или файл с путем $path

```
chmod($path, 0777)
```

тут подробное описание команды с кучей разнообразных примеров  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chmod.php